# Where do I add the for Each loop to create new item every time?

Tags: javascript, foreach, innerhtml

I know I must do a for each loop so that when a new task is created it adds the new task to the array and not replace the current one.

Currently my `addEventListener` is only creating a task.

```js
let listArray = []

let date = Date.now()
let id = Math.floor((Math.random() + date) * 3000)

let add = document.querySelector("#add")


add.addEventListener("click", (event) => {

  let input = document.querySelector("#User-Input input")
  let list = document.querySelector(".list")
  list.classList.add("todo")

  list.innerHTML = `
        <div data-type="${id}"></div>
        <p>${input.value}</p>
        `

  listArray.push(list)
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="User-Input">

    <input id="text-area" type="text">
    <button id="add">Add</button>
  </div>

  <div class="list">

  </div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(".list")` will always return only the **first** element with class "list".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overwriting `list.innerHTML`, you can append to it:

```js
let listArray = []

let date = Date.now()
let id = Math.floor((Math.random() + date) * 3000)

let add = document.querySelector("#add")


add.addEventListener("click", (event) => {

  let input = document.querySelector("#User-Input input")
  let list = document.querySelector(".list")
  list.classList.add("todo")

  // HERE!
  list.innerHTML += `
        <div data-type="${id}"></div>
        <p>${input.value}</p>
        ` 

  listArray.push(list)
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="User-Input">

    <input id="text-area" type="text">
    <button id="add">Add</button>
  </div>

  <div class="list">

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop (or the array for that matter). At the moment you're *replacing* the HTML of the list element rather than *adding* to it. You can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) for that. It gives you the option of where to add the new HTML - here we're using `beforeend`.

Note you can cache all of your elements outside of the handler, but you should add the code that creates the `id` inside the handler (or add it to a separate function which is called in the handler) so that the `id` is different for each new todo.

(In this example I'm also emptying the input box after each submission, and refocusing the cursor in the box ready for the next entry.)

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#User-Input input');
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
const add = document.querySelector('#add')

input.focus();

add.addEventListener("click", (event) => {

  const date = Date.now();
  const id = Math.floor((Math.random() + date) * 3000);

  const html = `
    <div class="todo" data-id="${id}">
      <p>${input.value}</p>
    </div>
  `;

  list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

  input.value = '';
  input.focus();

});
```

```css
.list { width: 80%; }
.todo { background-color: #efefef;}
.todo p { padding: 0.25em; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="User-Input">

    <input id="text-area" type="text">
    <button id="add">Add</button>
  </div>

  <div class="list"></div>

</div>
```